# iOS Webview and jFontSize

Tags: html, ios, webview, size

I'm trying to use [jFontSize](http://www.jfontsize.com/) in a local html page to be displayed in a WebView.
The script should allow the user to change the text size and it does. However this is no longer the case when I add 
 to the text.
I tried using [another script](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/use-the-jquery-ui-to-control-the-size-of-your-text/) but the same problem persists.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir = "ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.jfontsize-1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.corner-2.09.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="shCore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="shBrushJScript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="shBrushXml.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="shBrushCss.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="funcoes.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jfontsize.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="shCoreDefault.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-m2" href="#">A-</a>
        <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-d2" href="#">A</a>
        <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-p2" href="#">A+</a>
        <p class="some-class-name2" dir="rtl" align = "right">Hello<br>world</p>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('.some-class-name2').jfontsize({
            btnMinusClasseId: '#jfontsize-m2',
            btnDefaultClasseId: '#jfontsize-d2',
            btnPlusClasseId: '#jfontsize-p2',
            btnMinusMaxHits: 1,
            btnPlusMaxHits: 7,
            sizeChange: 7
                                         });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The page works fine on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the initialize code in document load -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //jfontsize increase
     $('.some-class-name2').jfontsize({
            btnMinusClasseId: '#jfontsize-m2',
            btnDefaultClasseId: '#jfontsize-d2',
            btnPlusClasseId: '#jfontsize-p2',
            btnMinusMaxHits: 1,
            btnPlusMaxHits: 7,
            sizeChange: 7
         });
});
```

It should work fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I will not get a chance to test your code as I'm no longer working on iOS, at least for the time being that is. Anyways, thank you for your reply.